# Differences between android framebuffer and linux framebuffer

Tags: framebuffer

Are there any differences between android framebuffer and linux framebuffer.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 2):

Android uses standard Linux framebuffer as described here: http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/display_drivers.html